# Can you inherit from abstract class a method and change its generic type to a specific one?

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

I would like to inherit a function from a base class and would like its parameter to match a certain class that changes based on the inherited class, for example

Base class

```
abstract class BaseList {
    abstract fun <T : BaseItem> addItem(item: T)
}
```

inherited class

```
class SupermarketList : BaseList() {
    override fun <T : BaseItem> addItem(item: T) {
    }
}
```

I would like to change the type `BaseItem` in the inherited class to another type based on the class. For example, change it to `Supermarket` item, like so:

```
class SupermarketList : BaseList() {
    override fun <T : SupermarketItem> addItem(item: T) {
    }
}
```

Notice the `Supermarket` item.

I am not sure generics is the best approach here; should it implement an interface? Is there another way do this, eg implement an argument for the function based on the class?

To be clear, the code above is working, but it seems to me like bad practice. What happens if by mistake I pass to the function another type than the type I want, which is also a subtype of BaseItem so it's accepted?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is a ‘self type’.  Unfortunately, this isn't available in Kotlin.  (So far; there have long been [discussions](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371) on adding them.)

[This](https://medium.com/@jerzy.chalupski/emulating-self-types-in-kotlin-d64fe8ea2e62) article discusses some workarounds.

In particular, you might be able to work around it by parameterising your base class, using that parameter type as the argument type for your function, and then supplying (or further restricting) that type in your subclasses.  It's a bit awkward (in particular, uses of your base class would need to supply the parameter too), but might work.

The other common suggestion is to replace your member function by an extension function.